# KDB: How to serialize a table for a union join within kdb-tick architecture?

Tags: kdb

Im trying to modify the kdb-tick architecture to support a union join on incoming data and the local rdb table.
I have modified the `upd` function in the tick.q file to the following:

```
ups:{[t;x]ts"d"$a:.z.P;
    if[not -16=type first first x;a:"n"$a;x:$[0>type first x;a,x;(enlist(count first x)#a),x]];
    f:key flip value t;pub[t;$[0>type first x;enlist f!x;flip f!x]];if[l;l enlist (`ups;t;x);i+:1];};
```

With `ups:uj` subsequently set in the subscriber files.
My question relates to how one might serialize a table row before publishing it within the `.u.ups[]` function.
I.e. given a table:

```
second     |  amount price 
-----------|----------------
02:46:01   |  54     9953.5
02:46:02   |  54     9953.5
02:46:03   |  54     9953.5
02:46:04   |  150    9953.5    
02:46:05   |  150    9954.5
```

How should one serialize the first row `02:46:01   |  54     9953.5` such that it can be sent via the `.u.ups` function to subscribers whereby uj will be run between the row and the local table on the subscribers.
Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this might help:

1. You can't set `ups:uj` in the subscribers because the table name is being passed as a symbol so the subscriber will effectively try to do

`` uj[`tab1;tab2] ``

which won't work because `uj` doesn't accept table names (symbols) as input. You would have to instead set `ups` to

`ups:{x set value[x] uj y}`

2. A standard tickerplant is not designed to handle variable/changing schema - for good reason, it's generally not a good idea to have a schema that changes intraday. However your situation might warrant it so in that case you'd need to modify your `.u.ups` function to something like

```
\d .u
ups:{[t;x]ts"d"$a:.z.P;
    x:`time xcols update time:"n"$a from x;
    pub[t;$[98h=type x;x;1=count last x;enlist x;flip x]];if[l;l enlist (`ups;t;x);i+:1];};
\d .
```

and your feeder process would have to send kdb tables or kdb dictionaries to the `.u.ups` function. Since a feedhandler process is usually not a kdb process, it may or may not be possible to send tables/dictionaries to the tickerplant as normally the feedhandler would send lists (without column metadata). In your case you need to somehow supply the column metadata to the tickerplant on each update (or maybe you're doing that already?), as otherwise it won't know which columns are which.

In other words your feeder process could send either of the following:

```
(`.u.upd;`tab;([]col1:`a`b`c;col2:1 2 3))
(`.u.upd;`tab;`col1`col2!(`a;1))
(`.u.upd;`tab;`col1`col2!(`a`b;1 2))
```

Comment: Thanks again Terry, In analysis of the above basically what I'm trying to do is create a feature table that is representative of multiple sources, i.e. sentiment, market data etc. It is where aggregations across multiple tables will be made, and to this extent does not require high I/O (1/second) however from my analysis it would necessitate a dynamic schema, what in your opinion would be an effective way of accomplishing this?

Comment: The schema doesn't necessarily change intraday but is inherently linked to the configuration of the input feeds

Comment: I have thought of implementing a schema check that would check if the schema of the list obtained from .u.upd is different from that of the aggregation table and then updating the schema in that case, however I am unsure as to the implementation detail therin. Should I open/edit the question such that further details my problem statement?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume this is related to your previous few questions about disparate schemas. I'd like to suggest an alternative solution, which is only truly viable if you are using kdb version 3.6, which uses anymap. If you can narrow your schemas down to a minimal list of common columns, all other columns can be placed as dictionaries into a general column.

```
q)tab:([]sym:`$();col1:`float$();colGeneral:(::))
q)`tab upsert (`AAPL;3.454;(`colX`colY`colZ!(1;2.3;"abc")))
`tab
q)`tab upsert (`MSFT;3.0;(`colX`colY!(2;100.0)))
`tab
q)`tab upsert (`AMZN;100.0;((enlist `colX)!(enlist 10)))
`tab
q)tab
sym  col1  colGeneral
----------------------------------------
AAPL 3.454 `colX`colY`colZ!(1;2.3;"abc")
MSFT 3     `colX`colY!(2;100f)
AMZN 100   (,`colX)!,10
q)select colGeneral from tab
colGeneral
-----------------------------
`colX`colY`colZ!(1;2.3;"abc")
`colX`colY!(2;100f)
(,`colX)!,10
q)select sym, colGeneral @\: `colX from tab
sym  x
-------
AAPL 1
MSFT 2
AMZN 10
q)select sym, colGeneral @\: `colY from tab
sym  x
---------
AAPL 2.3
MSFT 100f
AMZN 0N
```

With 3.6 you can be saving this to disk in any splayed format (splayed, partitioned, segmented) and still easily query the data. The storage of such a table will likely be sub-optimal due to poor compression characteristics of the general column (assuming you wish to compress data), but it will be perfectly functional.

Integrating `uj` into standard ingestion procedure with each update will be computationally expensive. Using a general column and dictionary method will massively improve your ingestion speed. Below I've given a demonstration using the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57759918/8875915) given a previous answer to a related question of yours

```
q)table:()
q)row1:enlist `x`y`colX!(`AMZN;100.0;10)
q)table:table uj row
q)\ts:100000 table:table uj row1
13828 6292352
q)\ts:100000 `tab upsert (`AMZN;100.0;((enlist `colX)!(enlist 10)))
117   12746880
```

Comment: Thanks again Callum, In analysis of the above basically what I'm trying to do is create a feature table that is representative of multiple sources, i.e. sentiment, market data etc. It is where aggregations across multiple tables will be made, and to this extent does not require high I/O (1/second) however from my analysis it would necessitate a dynamic schema, what in your opinion would be an effective way of accomplishing this?

Comment: The schema doesn't necessarily change intraday but is inherently linked to the configuration of the input feeds

Comment: I have thought of implementing a schema check that would check if the schema of the list obtained from .u.upd is different from that of the aggregation table and then updating the schema in that case, however I am unsure as to the implementation detail therin. Should I open/edit the question such that further details my problem statement?